# I want to display a message on hovering the mouse on the ASP.NET label 

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-ajax

I have an ASP.NET Label. I want to display a message after hovering the mouse over the label.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **[tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tooltip.aspx)** attribute of the asp label.

```
<asp:Label id="label1" ToolTip="Text on mouse over" runat="server">My label</asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how to do it specifically with a label, but see if you can use the abbr tag. This will display some text but will display different text when hovered over.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Tooltip attribute like so:

```
<asp:Label ToolTip="A nice tooltip!" runat="server">Something</asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties of the icon/label.
And there you can find  "ToolTipText".
write the name on the message you want to display when mouse gets hover on it).